# Confirming many duplicate files are the same (diff)

Tags: refactoring, diff

The previous person to work on the project I'm updating had a bad habit of just copying all of the files into a new directory when we got a new client. So now I have 10 directories with over 100 files each and I'm fairly certain they are 99% the same. I would like to refactor the project and eliminate the duplicate code. Due to the number of files it is time prohibitive to use WinDiff and manually compare them to confirm. The files are .jsp files i.e. plain text files.

Is there a program that I can point at a directory and have it search all sub directories for files with a specific name and then run a diff on them all at once?

If not has anyone run into a similar issue and what is the most efficient way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

[DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) enables you to do directory comparison and merging.